# ¿Verificar y reemplazar (eventualmente) el último carácter de una cadena en PHP?

Tags: php, string

Realmente no sé cómo podría hacer esto de una forma óptima.

En una cadena como esta:

```
0600030703
0601000703
0600070700
```

Yo quisiera verificar si el último carácter es un `3` y reemplazarlo por un `4`.

El resultado esperado sería entonces:

```
0600030704
0601000704
0600070700
```

Mi idea es tener una función a la que le pase el valor completo, el valor que quiero cambiar `3` y el valor de reemplazo `4`, pero no sé cuál sería la mejor manera. Sé que con `substr` yo podría obtener el último valor y verificar si es `3`, pero no sé cómo reemplazarlo al mismo tiempo por el `4`.

¿Alguna idea o alguna función propia de PHP que haga esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera en la que lo solucione, es la siguiente, espero te sirva

```
    $cadena1 = "0600030703";
    $cadena2 = "0601000703";
    $cadena3 = "0600070700";
    function procesaCadena($cadena){
        if(substr($cadena,-1,1)==3) return substr($cadena,0,(strlen($cadena)-1))."4";
        else return $cadena;
    }
    echo procesaCadena($cadena1);
    echo "<br>";
    echo procesaCadena($cadena2);
    echo "<br>";
    echo procesaCadena($cadena3);
```

Comment: Era eso lo que buscaba, muchas gracias Fernando.

Answer (score 0):

Pues efectivamente puede hacerlo con el `substr` para obtener el último caracter, y luego usar `str_repeat` para reemplazarlo por el número deseado.

Algo como esto:

```
$resultado = substr($cadena, 0, -1).str_repeat('4', 1);
```

O más genérico:

```
$resultado = function($cadena, $caracter, $numero) {
  return substr($cadena, 0, -$numbero).str_repeat($caracter, $numero);
};
```

Con esto `substr($cadena, 0, -1)` obviamente le esta indicando que es la última posición de la `cadena` y con  `str_repeat('4', 1);` le esta indicando que lo sustituya por el número `4` una sola ves `1`.

**Solo cuando el caracter final sea un `3`:**

```
if (substr($cadena, -1) == '3')
{
    $resultado= substr($cadena, 0, -1).str_repeat('4', 1);
}
```

O como le comente, puede usar [rtrm](http://php.net/rtrim):

```
$resultado = rtrim($cadena, '3');
```

> Documentación :
>
> - [substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)
> - [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-repeat.php)

Comment: Gracias. Pero yo quiero que haga el cambio **solamente** cuando ese último carácter sea igual a `3`. Por eso puse en los resultados esperados un tercer valor que no es modificado porque termina en `0`, no en `3`. Mi dificultad es precisamente hacer la comparación.

Comment: pues debe usar `$resultado = rtrim($cadena, '3');` con esto si es un 3 lo eliminará

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, verifique :)

Comment: Agradezco tu interés, pero he verificado tu código y lamentablemente sólo funciona cuando la cadena termina en `3`. Se trataría de una función que acepte cualquier tipo de cadena. La respuesta de @FernandoFerretiz hace lo que estaba buscando. De todos modos, muchas gracias.